# Managing compound clips in Davinci Resolve 16

Tags: video-editor, editing, file-formats, davinci-resolve

I've made a couple compound clips in my Davinci resolve project. Right now, I need to open that project, manually copy required clips and paste them in a new project. Is there any way to create a catalogue or export these clips, so I could reuse them in new projects?
At the moment I could recreate these clips as simple PNG with transparency, but in the future I'm planning to reuse animated clips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Resolve, "Power Bins" are what you use to make elements available across projects.  Unfortunately, as of version 16.3, Resolve won't store Compound Clips, Multicam Clips or Fusion Clips inside a Power Bin.  However, in your case, a workaround is fairly straightforward.

Whether your image is static or animated; an exported still image, file sequence, or video is compatible with power bins.  Export what you need on the Deliver page, Re-import it, add it to the Power Bin, and you should be good to go.

One quick tip for the Export->Re-import step:  After you export anything in Resolve, after Resolve marks the Queue item "Complete," You can right-click on the complete item, and select "Reveal in Media Storage."  Resolve will then open the Media Page, and highlight the file in the browser.  From there, all you need to do is drag it to your Power Bin.

To enable Power Bins, on the Media page, go to the "View" menu, and near the bottom of the list, check "Show Power Bins."  If your media pool and/or media folders sidebar list is not visible, hit command-1 (mac) or control-1 (pc).

You do need to be careful with the way you handle transparency if you expect to use it.  Resolve doesn't "think" for its users the way some apps do.  It doesn't pre-suppose that you "meant" to include an alpha channel because your source sequence contains one, but your chosen export codec doesn't support it.  It won't give you an error, or a warning, or recommend a different codec.  It'll just do what it's told, and then you'll wonder why your backgrounds are black instead of transparent.  So, make sure you're exporting to a format that supports transparency if you need it, like prores4444.  If you're doing that already, and getting black backgrounds anyway, it's because your alpha pipe is broken on the color page; make sure that the last node's alpha output (blue square) is wired to the master alpha output.  If it's not wired to anything, right-click in the background of the node tree, and select "Add alpha output," then wire the blue square to the blue circle that appears.

The same caution applies to premultiplication.  If your antialiased edges appear too bright, or too dark, that's a premultiplication error, and the onus is on the user.  To change how Resolve interprets a clip's alpha math on the import side, right-click on the clip in the media pool, choose "Clip Attributes" and change "Alpha Mode" if necessary.  Note, however, it's possible to accidentally double-multiply, or double-divide on the export side, in which case no menu selection here will produce desired results.  See [here](http://www.spherevfx.com/written-training/miscellaneous-written-training/understanding-premultiplied-images/) and [here](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=121224).

And one final note.  While Resolve doesn't support Fusion *CLIPS* in Power Bins, it does support Fusion *COMPOSITIONS* in Power Bins.  So, if you need something more interactive than a flat export down the road, that's the direction you should explore; It's a great way to make titles, and lower-thirds that are re-usable across projects, which maintain a consistent look, yet remain flexible to edit.  Fusion is a complex topic on its own, and I encourage you to experiment with it, and ask specific questions as they arise.

Hope that helps, Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply, I've never seen "Power bins" and I'll try them out tonight! Do you know if there are any plans for supporting Compound Clips and other project files in the future?